# How to create Bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want to format output of a  json file, that I read in Angular. I want to use a bootstrap grid, but I tried and I had no success.The files are:

test.html

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <ul>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <li ng-repeat-start="pat in patients">
                        <strong> {{pat.name}}</strong>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">  
                    <li ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="diag in pat.diagnose">
                        {{diag.disease}}
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
</body>
```

test.js

```
 var App = angular.module('MyApp', []);

 App.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){
         $scope.patients = [];
         angular.forEach(data.patients, function(value, key){
           $scope.patients.push(value);
        });
   });
 });
```

test.json

```
{
     "patients": [
                {
                    "name": "Abcd", 
                    "diagnose":[    
                                {"disease":"Ddd"},
                                {"disease":"Rrrr"},
                                {"disease":"Aaaaa"}
                            ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Efghij", 
                    "diagnose":[ 
                                {"disease":"Hhhhh"}
                            ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Klmnop", 
                    "diagnose":[
                                {"disease":"Gggggg"}
                            ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Qrst", 
                    "diagnose":[
                                {"disease":"Oooooo"},
                                {"disease":"Xxxxxx"}
                            ]
                }
            ]
  }
```

I want to have on each row: Name (col 1), Disease (col2). (diseases listed vertically). Coul you help me plese

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```js
var App = angular.module('MyApp', []);

 App.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.patients = [
                {
                    "name": "Abcd", 
                    "diagnose":[    
                                {"disease":"Ddd"},
                                {"disease":"Rrrr"},
                                {"disease":"Aaaaa"}
                            ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Efghij", 
                    "diagnose":[ 
                                {"disease":"Hhhhh"}
                            ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Klmnop", 
                    "diagnose":[
                                {"disease":"Gggggg"}
                            ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Qrst", 
                    "diagnose":[
                                {"disease":"Oooooo"},
                                {"disease":"Xxxxxx"}
                            ]
                }
            ];

 });

angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="TestCtrl" class="container">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="pat in patients">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <strong> {{pat.name}}</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> 
                    <ul>
                      <li ng-repeat="diag in pat.diagnose">
                        {{diag.disease}}
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try this in full page when executing the snippet here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/6393/

```
<ul ng-repeat="pat in patientsList.patients">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <li>
          <strong> {{pat.name}}</strong>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <li ng-repeat="diag in pat.diagnose">
          {{diag.disease}}
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was very unclear. The grid structure I want to create the grid is :

```
Patient_1                    Disease_1_Patient_1
                             Disease_1_Patient_1
                             Disease_2_Patient_1
------------------------------------------------
Patient_2                    Disease_1_Patient_2
                             Disease_2_Patient_2
------------------------------------------------
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be useful for someone else. Finaly, I got the result I wanted.I changed the HTML file as follows (I'll show only the body section):

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="container" ng-repeat="pat in patients">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">{{pat.name}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><ul><li ng-repeat="diag in pat.diagnose">{{diag.disease}}</li></ul></div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </body>
```

I reach this result, by creating first a HTML table like this:

```
    <table ng-repeat="artist in artists">
        <tr>
            <td>{{artist.name}}</td>
            <td ><ul><li ng-repeat="album in artist.albums">{{album.title}}</li></ul></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then I replaced:

```
               <table>
```

with

```
              <div class="container">, 

               <tr>
```

with

```
               <div class="row">
```

and

```
               <td>
```

with

```
                <div class="col-xx-xx">
```